Prove that $A \cap A_\alpha=\emptyset$
The question :

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a countable set of Real numbers. For all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ we define a set $A_\alpha \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ as follows :
$$A_\alpha:=\{x+\alpha : x\in A\}$$
(i) Prove that there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A \cap A_\alpha=\emptyset$.
(ii)Prove that there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such for all two pairs of $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$  , $$A_{m\alpha}\cap A_{n \alpha}=\emptyset$$

What i have tried for part one:
Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ if $A \cap A_\alpha \neq\emptyset$ then there exist an element that is in $A$ and in $A_\alpha$ therefore we can write it in one way as $x+\alpha : x\in A$ and in another as $y \in A$ therefore we get that :
$$y=\alpha +x$$
$$\alpha=y-x$$
therefore we define $B:=\{\alpha : A \cap A_\alpha\neq\emptyset\}$ and we notice that $B$ is contained in $C:= \{y-x \in \mathbb{R}  | x,y \in A\}$ but i got no where from here, i think we need to show  that $C$ is countable (i dont know how) and then we get that $B$ is countable and beacuse $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable then there exist $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ that is not in $B$ and therefore $$A \cap A_\alpha=\emptyset$$
and for part two i think its from part one but i am not sure.

You're almost there. To show that $C$ is countable, try to use the fact that the map $A × A → C, (x, y) ↦ y-x$ is surjective.

Are you considering zero to be a natural number? If so, part 2 is false because $A_0\cap A_0\ne\emptyset$.

@JeanAbouSamra thanks ,  no i dont john.

Let us prove (ii). [$m=0,n=1$ gives (i)].
If this is not true, then, for any $\alpha$ there is a  point $x \in A_{n\alpha}\cap A_{m\alpha}$. Assume $n \neq m$. [(ii) is false for $m=n$].  We can write $x=a+n\alpha, x=b+m\alpha$  with $a, b \in A$. Thus, $\alpha=\frac {a-b}{m-n}$. The map $\alpha \mapsto (a,b,n,m)$ is  an injective map into a  countable set since a finite product of countable sets is countable. See: The cartesian product of a finite amount of countable sets is countable.
This makes $\mathbb R$ countable, a contradiction.

(i) Assume $A$ is sorted with $\delta$ being the smallest absolute difference between the consecutive numbers in $A$. Then any positive $\alpha < \delta$ would translate $A$ into a set that has no common elements with $A$.
(ii) Let $A_k$ be $A$ translated by a natural number $k$. Let $\delta_m$ and $\delta_n$ be the smallest differences between consecutive elements in $A_m$ and $A_n$ respectively. Then for any $\alpha < \min(\delta_m/m, \delta_n/n)$, $n\alpha$ and $m\alpha$ will translate $A$ into two sets with no common elements.
NOTE: This reasoning is not general enough since it does not work for all cases. As noted in the comment below, minimal $\delta$ need not exist, as in the sequence ${1/n}$, for example.

$\delta$ does not need to exist.

@Andrés E. Caicedo, Thanks. Indeed, $\delta$ may not exist. That case is completely overlooked in my answer. Should I remove the answer or add the comments to clarify?

@dnqxt its better to edit the answer
